# remove lines which have same string in column 1 and 2

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I have matrix with multiple rows and columns. I want to remove those lines which have same string in column one and two. For example file-

```
wheat_tae-miR1127       wheat_tae-miR1127       100.00  19      0 
wheat_tae-miR1131       wheat_tae-miR1131       100.00  22      0
wheat_tae-miR164        Rice_osa-miR164        100.00  21      0 
wheat_tae-miR164        Maize_miRBase_zma-miR164a-5p    100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Maize_zma-miR444a       100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Rice_osa-miR444a-3p_1   100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       wheat_tae-miR444a       100.00  21      0
```

desired output is-

```
wheat_tae-miR164        Maize_miRBase_zma-miR164a-5p    100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Maize_zma-miR444a       100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Rice_osa-miR444a-3p_1   100.00  21      0
```

Comment: Could you explain which line should be taken if there's more than one for a specific name? It's not clear in your example.

Comment: the string in column 1 & 2 is not fixed in all lines , it is variable. i want to take those lines which are not same in column 1 & 2.

Comment: What's the difference between `wheat_tae-miR1131` and `wheat_tae-miR1131`?

Comment: sorry that should be removed.

Comment: Please post your code and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can do this pretty easily with `awk`

```
awk -F' ' '$1!=$2' input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Awk solution:

```
awk '$1!=$2' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[0] ne $F[1]' file
```

Answer (score 1):

In perl, this is a tool for a hash. (Offering a perlish alternative because of the question tag).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $col1, $col2 ) = split;
    print unless ( $col1 eq $col2 );
}

__DATA__
wheat_tae-miR1127       wheat_tae-miR1127       100.00  19      0 
wheat_tae-miR1131       wheat_tae-miR1131       100.00  22      0
wheat_tae-miR164        Rice_osa-miR164        100.00  21      0 
wheat_tae-miR164        Maize_miRBase_zma-miR164a-5p    100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Maize_zma-miR444a       100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Rice_osa-miR444a-3p_1   100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       wheat_tae-miR444a       100.00  21      0
```

Seems to do the trick, but I do get an extra line compared to yours?

```
wheat_tae-miR164        Rice_osa-miR164        100.00  21      0 
wheat_tae-miR164        Maize_miRBase_zma-miR164a-5p    100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Maize_zma-miR444a       100.00  21      0
wheat_tae-miR444a       Rice_osa-miR444a-3p_1   100.00  21      0
```

Comment: Whenever you write `split /\s+/` you allmost certainly want `split ' '`. A single literal space is a special case for `split` and it differs from the former in that, if there happens to be leading whitespace in the string to be split, it doesn't return null string as the first element of the list. It is also the default if no parameter is specified, so your statement would be better written as just `my ( $col1, $col2 ) = split`